# How do I do separate tasks on multiple screens which are duplicated?

Tags: multiple-monitors, duplicate

I have multiple monitors and have duplicated the screens, but how do I do separate tasks on each screen?

Answer (score 1):

You **extend** the desktop not duplicate. Then you can use them independently.

Comment: But then how do I get the start menu and all the icons to appear on both screens?

Comment: Do you honestly not know how to use google?

Comment: Google brought me to this site. Silly me if I thought I could just get a quick answer instead of scrolling through a billion unrelated questions.